# Mocking chained calls in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I am trying to test the following class using `unittest` and the `mock` library:

```
class Connection(object):
    def __init__(self, cookie):
    self.connect = None
    self.session = Session()
    self.session.load(cookie)
    # do some stuff with self.session
    self.some_info = self.session.data['the_info']
```

How could I test if when I create an instance of `Connection`, depending on the return of the `Session` instance, I assert if `self.some_info` is with the value I am expecting?

I wish to use the mock library. In its documentation I have an example of mocking chained calls (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-chained-calls), but it isn't very clear of how I can adapt it to my problem.

The `Session.load(cookie)` method sets some attributes in the `Session` instance. I would like to set this values fixed for my tests for every value of cookie.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

Assume `Connection` is located in module `package.module.connection`

The following code should be how you would test your session:

```
import mock


class TestConnection(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('package.module.connection.Session')
    def test_some_info_on_session_is_set(self, fake_session):
        fake_session.data = {'the_info': 'blahblah'}
        cookie = Cookie()
        connection = Connection(cookie)
        self.assertEqual(connection.some_info, 'blahblah')
        fake_session.load.assert_called_once_with(cookie)
```

Comment: I didn't understand the patch decorator before. After your answer, I read again the mock documentation and see that is the better way (or the only one :-) ) to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately the patch decorater is ok if I am trying to change the return of some function of Session class. But if I try to change the data dictionary, the test result in:
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Renne your question is unclear. What are you trying to do exactly? Can you please post a snippet that demonstrates your problem? Also, your question, thusly, changes from its original form.